# Maven building Flex 3.5 app, java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-flex, maven-2, flex3, maven

I'm getting this error on a Mac running Snow Leopard and maven 2.2.1, building a Adobe Flex 3.5 application.

I've been through the process of setting my MAVEN_OPTS env variable, it's set to -Xmx1024m

When maven finishes, the final memory is nowhere near this limit:

[INFO] Final Memory: 46M/123M

I'm not sure if this is a red herring - garbage collection has been run, so *that's* why it's so far under the 1024M limit, but it's the only strange thing I can see. I'm working on a team of devs who can all build fine with a heap space maximum of 1024M, they're on Windows or Snow Leopard boxes. Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Maven may fork off separate processes several times during the course of the execution; these generally cannot be assumed to share the same tuning.  MAVEN_OPTS only applies to the maven execution.  The fact that it finishes successfully (if Maven itself hit the heap limit it would just exit) is a good indicator that it's a subprocess that's too big.

A full error report would pinpoint where in the process it is failing.  The [flexmojos FAQ](http://flexmojos.sonatype.org/faq.html) would seem to indicate that the flexmojos goals *do* adhere to the MAVEN_OPTS settings.  I'm assuming you're using flexmojos.  So then my guess would be that it's possibly tests that are failing?  You should post the relevant parts of the error trace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, it actually turned out that I was inadvertantly executing maven as administrator, which didn't get the same MAVEN_OPTS, so this was why it got an out of memory exception. Doh!